# How to display contents from database into tabular format in django?

Tags: python, django

```
class Venue(
    RandomIDMixin,
    TimeStampedModelMixin,
    models.Model
):

# Venue model for storing metadata about a place.

VENUE_TYPES = (
    ('shul', 'Shul'),
    ('hall', 'Hall'),
    ('residence', 'Residence'),
    ('other', 'Other'),
)

address1 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
address2 = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
city = models.CharField(max_length=256)
country = models.ForeignKey('countries.Country', null=True)
description = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
display_address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default="")
image = models.FileField(
    blank=True, null=True,
    upload_to=prefix_venue_images, default='{}{}'.format(settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.VENUE_DEFAULT_IMAGE))
name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, default="")
region = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, default="")
venue_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=VENUE_TYPES, default='hall')
website_url = models.URLField(max_length=512, blank=True, default="")

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('name', 'address1', 'city')

def __str__(self):
    return '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format(self.name, self.city, self.region)
```

I want to show above information in table format on admin site. I am a beginner having zero knowledge of django.

Comment: You need to register model in Admin.py

Comment: i have done that.

Comment: what are you seeing on your admin site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show this model on django admin as tabular format you need to edit your `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Venue

class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'city', 'region')

admin.site.register(Venue, VenueAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, all you have to do is go to your `admin.py` in your Django app and add the following lines:

```
from path.to.models import Venue

admin.site.register(Venue)
```

I suggest you follow the django tutorial, and start at the beginning:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/